# Adding images in gallery of emulator

Tags: android, image, android-emulator

I want to display images in my application. But in emulator there no any picture present by default. So it needs to add some images to emulator. I tried it with adding images in sdcard by could't be successful. Please specify steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use DDMS or adb push command to push images onto sdcard. Make sure to run MediaScanner from dev tools, post that.

Comment: Thank you. It was so easy and very helpful.