# How to see pushed images to sd card in emulator

Tags: android

I create an emulator with 2000MB SD Card size and push files to it as you can see in image but i can't see these image files in gallery application in emulator. how can i see the images in gallery application?
link of file to see my emulator and files that pushed to it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I found in two other SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062806/adding-images-in-gallery-of-emulator) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170214/image-saved-to-sdcard-doesnt-appear-in-androids-gallery-app), Make sure to run MediaScanner from dev tools after you push the images to the SD card so the emulator re-scans the SD card for new media.

Answer (score 2):

Running media scanner is simple, all you have to do is

- Run your android virtual device on the emulator
- Click on the "Dev Tools" icon in the menu
- In the list view of settings options, scroll down, click, and launch "Media Scanner"

Goto, windows -> AVD Manager and click Refresh. Now on the emulator, if you click the gallery icon, you get the pictures that you pushed onto your SDCard

Answer (score 0):

If the "Dev Tool" --> "Media Scanner" crash you can run this:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

it is faster then a reboot